# Can the weighted average of the ratio of two datasets be informed by the ratio of the individual weighted averages?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Say I have two datasets $x_i$ and $y_i$ each of the same length.  I also have corresponding non-negative weights where $\sum_i^N a_i = \sum_i^N b_i = 1$.

The ratio of the weighted averages would be

$$ s = \frac{\sum_i a_i x_i}{\sum_i b_i y_i} $$

Now let’s say we only had access to the set of weights and the set of $z_i$’s where $z_i = \frac{x_i}{y_i}$ (but we do not know the individual $x_i$ and $y_i$). Is it possible to derive a new set of unique weights using the previously supplied weights on $z$ such that we can calculate what the unknown **unique** $s$ must be?  In other words, is there a set $w_i$ for which

$$s = \frac{\sum_i a_i x_i}{\sum_i b_i y_i} = \sum_i w_i z_i$$

holds?  I have tried my hand at the algebra and my intuition says there does not exist a solution because I can arbitrarily pick say $(x_1, y_1)$ and multiply by a constant $c$ to preserve the corresponding $z_1$ value but change $s$. Thus, we would need some information on the individual $x$ and $y$ values or relationship.  So I do not believe we have enough information, but how would we go about proving this algebraically?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not enough information.

The way you would go about proving it is by exhibiting a counterexample.  Specifically, find values for $a_i,b_i,z_i$'s and one assignment to $x_i,y_i$'s that leads to one value of $s$, and another assignment $x_i,y_i$'s that leads to a different value of $s$. It suffices to take  $N=2$ and construct a counterexample.  If you play with some concrete example values for $N=2$ you should be able to construct such a counterexample yourself.

Answer (score -2):

i
Weighted Average Ratio=
∑
i
​
b
i
​
y
i
​

∑
i
​
a
i
​
x
i
​

​

Now, let's consider the ratio of the individual weighted averages:

## ∑
i
a
i
x
i
∑
i
b
i
y
i

(
∑
i
a
i
)
(
∑
i
a
i
x
i
∑
i
a
i
)
(
∑
i
b
i
)
(
∑
i
b
i
y
i
∑
i
b
i
)
∑
i
​
b
i
​
y
i
​

∑
i
​
a
i
​
x
i
​

## ​

(∑
i
​
b
i
​
)(
∑
i
​
b
i
​

∑
i
​
b
i
​
y
i
​

​
)
(∑
i
​
a
i
​
)(
∑
i
​
a
i
​

∑
i
​
a
i
​
x
i
​

​
)
​

In this expression,
∑
i
a
i
x
i
∑
i
a
i
∑
i
​
a
i
​

∑
i
​
a
i
​
x
i
​

​
is the weighted average of
x
i
x
i
​
with weights
a
i
a
i
​
, and
∑
i
b
i
y
i
∑
i
b
i
∑
i
​
b
i
​

∑
i
​
b
i
​
y
i
​

​
is the weighted average of
y
i
y
i
​
with weights
b
i
b
i
​
.

Therefore, the ratio of the individual weighted averages is the same as the ratio of the overall weighted averages:

## ∑
i
a
i
x
i
∑
i
b
i
y
i

∑
i
a
i
x
i
∑
i
a
i
÷
∑
i
b
i
y
i
∑
i
b
i
∑
i
​
b
i
​
y
i
​

∑
i
​
a
i
​
x
i
​

## ​

∑
i
​
a
i
​

∑
i
​
a
i
​
x
i
​

​
÷
∑
i
​
b
i
​

∑
i
​
b
i
​
y
i
​

​

So, yes, the ratio of the overall weighted averages can be expressed in terms of the ratio of the individual weighted averages.